# Bad masonry element: null - using wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, masonry, imagesloaded

I am writing a wordpress plugin in php. In that plugin I output pictures with a little text and want to do that with masonry.

When I initialize masonry in HTML, it seems to work, but the pictures overlap:

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
```

Therefore I am trying to use "Imagesloaded" (by the same developer?).

But as I see it, before I can use ImagesLoaded I need to get Masonry up and running with javascript. When I initialize Masonry in my plugin_scripts.js I get an error on the frontend:

plugin_scripts.js:

```
jQuery(function() {

alert("hallo");
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});

});
```

Console Error in Frontend:

```
Bad masonry element: null 
masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2:1
q masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2:1
d masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2:1
(anonymous function) schnoogle_scripts_frontend.js?ver=3.9.2:10
j jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:2
k.fireWith jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:2
n.extend.ready jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:2
K jquery.js?ver=1.11.0:2
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Masonry can't find your container for some reason.  I assume you've tried the obvious, such as making sure `#container` is actually on the page.

If you're using jQuery (which you are), you can use jQuery's selector engine.

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

Ensure this is within a `document.ready` call, so that you're doing it after the rest of the page is ready.

Comment: I think this doesnt work in wordpress:$
The $ is used differently in WP

Comment: You may be in `noConflict` mode.  Simply do `jQuery('#container')` instead

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function(){
  //call masonry
}
```

You should load html before call masonry so query selector can find query

Answer (score 0):

if using vanilla js in WordPress, if you enqueue a script it's everywhere.  to solve this I query to see if the element is on the page for initializing Masonry.

```
var masonry_element = document.querySelector( '.masonry' );
if( typeof( masonry_element ) != 'undefined' && masonry_element != null ){
    var msnry = new Masonry( '.masonry', { ... } );
}
```